# I can't restore unallocated disk space to the original volume

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning

how can I make this unallocated space usable again without wiping the drive - i try to 'extend volume' but it comes up with this error:
[image]

Comment: I have tried re scanning

Comment: I previously had ubuntu on that partition if that helps?

Comment: You should be able to use [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php) to move the unallocated partition in between Big Disk and the 512 MB partition.  Then, you should be able to extend Big Disk into the the unallocated space that is adjacent to its right side.

Comment: The point is that you can extend only into _adjacent_ free space. Your simplest solution is to create a new partition and use it for a specialised purpose, eg back-ups, media files (but not video!), shared files, etc. This avoids the hazards of partition manipulation, which needs you to back up the whole disc before you start. Alternatively, if you're not going to boot from that disc, you can delete the EFI partition and then you can easily extend `D:` to fill the whole disc.

Comment: nice one GParted worked - had a bit of trouble with secure boot violation, but got there in the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I booted [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php) live DVD to move the EFI (512MB) partition to the end of the drive - then used Windows Disk Management to extend the D:\ volume into the adjacent unallocated space.

I'm still not sure of the implications of being forced to convert the drive from basic to dynamic? is the EFI partition nessessary? - it's undeleteable using Windows Disk Management.